# how to reshape a frame data in np 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have data in 3d array like:

```
[[[ 41  57  64 255]
  [ 57  76  79 255]
  [ 92 113 115 255]
  ...
  [ 70  89  80 255]
  [106 127 118 255]
  [140 161 152 255]]]
```

`array.shape = (360, 640, 4)`

and I want to turn it to be something like:

```
[[[120 125 110]
  [120 125 110]
  [120 126 109]
  ...
  [192 207 189]
  [194 207 189]
  [195 208 190]]]
```

`array.shape = (480, 640, 3)`

This two set for data is take out from two different camera. 
Can I reshape array? After reshape, a frame will show correctly?

I try to use np.reshape() and convert to list and pop, but list method very slow and cannot display correctly

np.reshape
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 921600 into shape (360,640,3)`

Comment: How did you get that output from the input?

Comment: send the code what have you tried so far

Comment: @Divakar I am using `cv2` to capture frame. This is a two different camera output. first output is kinect and second is a normal camera.

Comment: @EMKAY I try `np.reshape` and `list` method. `np.reshape` fail to reshape and list method cannot show image correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first image seems to be a 360 x 640 rgba image, and the second seems to be a 480 x 640 rgb image. So, what you can do is pad the first with zeros and remove the last element of its 3rd dimension.

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.arange(360*640*4).reshape((360, 640, 4)) # example
array2 = np.arange(480*640*3).reshape((480, 640, 3)) # example

zeros = np.zeros(array2.shape, dtype=np.int32)
zeros[60:-60,:,:] = array1[:,:,:-1]
modified_array1 = zeros

print modified_array1.shape, array2.shape
```

produces:

```
(480, 640, 3) (480, 640, 3)
```

Comment: the image size remain unchange, I checked `array1[:,:,:-1]` is ok. Thank you for your answer

Comment: What do you mean the size remain unchanged? Note that `zeros = np.zeros(array2.shape, dtype=np.int32)` uses array **2**'s shape, and in `zeros[60:-60,:,:] = array1[:,:,:-1]` it uses array **1**'s values.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of the difference in the total number of elements in the two cases:

```
360*640*3=691200
480*640* 3=921600
```

Numpy reshape only works when the number of elements in the previous and reshaped array are the same.

You can try padding with 0's if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken this sample example and it worked for me.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((360,640,4))
print(x.shape)
print(x)

y = x.reshape(480,640,3)
print(y)
print(y.shape)
```